# ¿Cómo puedo implementar socket.io o la instancia de socket.io en diferentes partes del proyecto?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

¿Cómo puedo implementar socket.io o la instancia de socket.io en diferentes partes del proyecto o en diferentes documentos? Es decir, tengo la declaración e instancia de express y de socket.io en el documento index.js, pero quiero implementar los métodos de socket.io para enviar datos en otro documento donde están los controladores.

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const htpp = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(htpp)

io.on('connection', socket=>{
   // all socket events here
   console.log('Un cliente se ha conectado');
  socket.on('sala',(data)=>{
    console.log("Esta es la sala que manda el puñetas del cliente",data);
  })
  // Manejo de eventos del cliente
  socket.on('message', (data) => {
    console.log('Mensaje recibido:', data);
    // Emitir un evento a todos los clientes conectados 
    
  });
 var data = "hola, soy el servidor";
  io.emit('message', "así que no llego nada he");
  // Manejo de desconexión del cliente
  socket.on('disconnect', () => { 
    console.log('Cliente desconectado');
  });

});

// Magic Lines
htpp.prependListener("request", (req, res) => {
   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
});


// instead of "*" your can also add the other domain/servername
htpp.listen(7000, () => {
   console.log("This is the socket server running");
});
```

data.controller.js

```
import {getConnection} from "./../database/database";
// controlador para insertar datos 
const insertData = async(req,res)=>{
    const { 
         temperature,
         pressure, 
         altitud, 
         air_quality
         
        } = req.body;
      
    try{
        
        const connection = await getConnection();
        const result = await connection.query(`call sp_StoreMeteorologicalData('${temperature}','${pressure}','${altitud}','${air_quality}')`);
        res.status(200).json({status:"Well done!", message:"Datos registrados con exito"});


    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json(error.message);
    }
}
export const methods = {
    getRealTimeData,
    insertData
};
```

Ya intente escribir toda la instancia de socket.io en los controladores pero no me funciono, entonces quisiera saber si es posible o si cuando se sube a producción tengo que tener un documento especifico para el servidor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes intentar exportar la instancia de socket.io globalmente and acceder a ella cuando desees.

```
app.set('socketio', io);// aqui asignas el socket global
```

entonces cuando lo necesites en este caso el controlador puede hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
const io = req.app.get('socketio');
io.emit(<nombre-del-evento>, <mensaje>)
```

Comment: Hola! Martinez gracias por tu respuesta, nada más tengo una pregunta que es "req" en "req.app.get('socketio');" ?, ya probe tu codigo y me marca que no esta definida
"

Comment: Martinez disculpa, otra cosa, lo que trato es  implementar  los eventos de  socket.io pero dentro de un controlador ya echo, de ante mano muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola @Miguel__Olvera req es el parametro de tu controlador aqui -> async(req,res)

Comment: y "app" es porque se importa app del documento de index.js de express?

Comment: Exacto la app es la que esta en el index

Comment: te agradezco, lo que me dijiste funciono correctamente pero no entiendo por que? pero no importa, muchas gracias, gracias

Comment: oiye otra duda, en producción también funciona igual o tengo que modificar algo?